# MS Graph API: Embeddable PDF preview link with zoom/page parameters

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

As stated in the [MS Graph Driveitem Preview Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-body), the parameters `page` and `zoom` are available in the request body.

When sending a request like this (for a preview of a PDF file)...

```
POST /me/drive/items/{itemId}/preview
Content-type: application/json

{
    "page": "2",
    "zoom": 0.5
}
```

... the resolved URL contains this (decoded) parameter:

```
embed={"p":2,"z":0,5}
```

**The preview doesn't change at all**: The zoom option is still the default and the started page is still the first one.

The `page` in the request should be a string as specified in the docs, when using a number, you get a `400 Bad Request`.

I've tried to use different zoom values, as they are not specified by MS, but no luck.

Interestingly, when generating a preview link for a docx, the parameters are correctly resolved and used by the preview. So it might be a problem for PDF-files only?

The docs says the following:
`The 'page' and 'zoom' options may not be available for all preview apps, but will be applied if the preview app supports it.`

Comment: As doc states : `Note: The preview action is currently only available on SharePoint and OneDrive for Business.`. Are you trying to show a file on either of the platform (not onedrive personal account)